# Can I narrow a union of arrays?

Tags: typescript

I have a union which looks something like this:

```
type MyUnion = string[] | number[];
```

So it's always an array, of either strings or numbers.

I'd like to know if the array I'm dealing with is an array of strings or an array of numbers. But type narrowing doesn't seem to work:

```
const arr: string[] | number[] = [];
if (typeof arr[0] === "string") {
   // arr has the type (string[] | number[])
}
```

So how can I type narrow `arr` to one of the union's types?

Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhgUwM4wGKQBQCGATkQFzJZFwQDmA2gLrIA+yEYAtgEZpGMCU5AG4I4AE2ABvYMlnI4IZHhgBPAA5oEi4nwAMTALxHkAIkrUaJ-smly7yHTLkBfYK6A

Answer (score 2):

You can use type guards.

```
function isStringArray(arr: string[] | number[]): arr is string[] {
  return typeof arr[0] === "string";
}

const arr: string[] | number[] = [];

if (isStringArray(arr)) {
  // arr is type string[]
} else {
  // arr is type number[]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to achieve that:

```
export function isStringArray(array: string[] | number[]): array is string[] {
  return typeof array[0] === "string";
}
```

or you can do it generic way to check if any array is a string array

```
export function isStringArray<T>(array: T[]): array is string[] {
  return array.every(element => typeof element === "string");
}
```

then based on your code

```
if (isStringArray(arr)) {
  // arr has type string[]
}
```